# pointer to 2d array, program compiling but throwing segmentation fault at run time

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a following function in my class.

```
bool ncread_llt::get_dataArray_atOnce (float **data)
{
    startp[0]=0;
    countp[0]=ntime;
    float vdata[ntime][nlat][nlon];
    dataVar.getVar(startp, countp, &vdata);
    int offset=0;
    for(int t =0; t<ntime; t++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nlat - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nlon - 1; j++)
            {
                offset=i*nlat+j;
                data[t][offset]=vdata[t][i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return(true);
}
```

and I call it in my main program like this

```
  float **rain[ntime][rain_pts];  //I get segfault in the next line.
  ncf1.get_dataArray_atOnce (**rain); //ncf1 is an object of the classs ncread_llt
```

This thing works with vector notation but I need to use a  library function which needs 2d array as input. I dont know what mistake Iam doing here. I have tried several combination of pointer notation but it doesnt compile and when it compiles (the above combination) it gets segmentation fault. Is there anything wrong with this code and why it compiles.

Comment: Could you post the compile errors you're getting and their associated line numbers?

Comment: ../simplyMapBase/swlib/ncio.hh:45: note: candidates are: bool ncread_llt::get_dataArray_atOnce(double**)
../simplyMapBase/swlib/ncio.hh:46: note:                 bool ncread_llt::get_dataArray_atOnce(float**)

when I call function as ncf1.get_dataArray_atOnce (rain);

Comment: Most immediately, I don't know who told you that `type **var` and type `var[n][m];` are equivalent, but you can tell them they're *wrong*. They are not. You're declaring a `[ntime][rain_pts]` array of pointer-to-pointer-to-float, then double dereferencing it (effectively retrieving rain[0][0], an indeterminate a pointer-to-pointer-to-float) and sending it to `get_dataArray_atOnce()`. As written, there is no way `data` can be properly dereferenced in `get_dataArray_atOnce()`.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig, I tried using the method given in the book but that needs to know at least one array bound. I want to know some way to get big array of values from the function. now im doing everything with vector and converting that into an array of desired size and shape. That's going to be slower.

Comment: I have made a program using vectors and its works fine untill im reading the data and printing it to cout. Howevere, when I make arrays to store this data it shows segfault at the declaration line. It seems like my arrays are too big for this laptop to handle. Im still not sure if something is wrong with the above code.

Comment: Note how C-style multidimensional arrays come in two varieties: all values in continuous memory block, with fixed dimensions (except the last), and then array of pointers (to arrays of pointers (to arrays of pointers...)) to one-dimensional arrays of values. Both can be adressed the same way with [] but are very different in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This line `float **rain[ntime][rain_pts];` creates and allocates memory for a 2-dimensional array of *pointers* (lets call this array `A`) to 2-dimensional float array each (pointers to `ntime*rain_pts` data arrays). Memory for those data arrays is *not* allocated at this point.

`**rain` dereferences array of pointers `A`, and gets first pointer (uninitialized yet), which is then passed to `get_dataArray_atOnce` function. Because pointer is uninitialized dereferencing it causes undefined behavior.

If you simply want to pass 2-dimensional array of `ntime*rain_pts` floats to your function, you can create it like this:

```
float **rain = new float*[ntime];
for (int i = 0; i < ntime; ++i)
{
    rain[i] = new float[rain_pts];
}
```

Than pass it like:

```
ncf1.get_dataArray_atOnce (rain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Serg lef, I did it the following way and its working.
I didn't know the concept of allocating memory and pointers very well.

```
float **rain;
rain=new float *[ntime];
for (int i=0; i<ntime; i++)
    rain[i]=new float[rain_pts];
```

and then

```
ncf1.get_dataArray_atOnce (rain);
```

Thank you all for your replies.